# Face Detector without using/displaying any ui

Tags: android

I have to detect a face without opening camera Ui or surface view.
like having a back ground service which detects face without any UI.
if any one have idea so please help me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/FaceDetector.html